# Core Ui CDateRangePicker calendars bug

Tags: core-ui

calendars={2} is set by default, but in certain cases, for some reason, only one calendar is displayed. Component CDateRangePicker. How can I fix this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDXjn.png)

how to make sure there are always 2 calendars